# Setting up a Rails app with a react front end

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, jsbundling-rails

I'm trying to set up a Rails app with a react front end, as indicated in this post:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-a-react-frontend

However, webpacker is now retired: https://github.com/rails/webpacker#webpacker-has-been-retired-

I've followed the steps here for using jsbundling but I'm not sure what else would be necessary to get the app to work: https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/

UPDATE: I've followed the steps here and I'm able to render a component as DHH demonstrated:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chiu-0EVW3g
Now I just need to figure out how the index and app components should be configured as would normally be the case in a react app.

Could anyone advise on the configuration I would need in order to get this working? Thank you!